# Iframe Issue : Refused to display issue in iframe

Tags: javascript, css

I'm getting below error in my JS code:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.brokerforum.com/electronic-components-search-en.jsa?originalFullPartNumber=%7bITEM%7d&x=0&y=0&hasNoSearchCriteria=false'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

What can I do to overcome it?

Comment: There's nothing you can do, unless you're controlling the server loading that page.

Comment: Hey Jitihin - I would encourage you to add some more details like the code block which is causing the issue. More details will be very helpful for the community to get to the root cause of the problem you're facing.